# Who/what "drooping down" refers to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "X looked at Y's pale, delicate neck, exposed above the open collars,
> **drooping gently down like thin mist**, and couldn't help but suggest, "Then[...]".

In this case is A) X the one drooping down while looking and suggesting? (so drooping is a predicate for X) Or B) is it the neck of Y that is being pale, exposed and drooping (so drooping down is partecipal for Y's neck)? Or maybe it's even C) collars to be drooping down?

Comment: It makes no sense. Where did you find this? It is normal to state the origin of text which you cannot understand.

Comment: Ambiguous. Probably the neck; maybe the collars. Unlikely to be X.

Comment: When my neck starts drooping like mist, I'll make an appointment to see my doctor.

Comment: "Collars"? "Thin mist"? It's gbberish.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to imagine a garment with more than one collar. And what mist droops, gently or otherwise?